# Can I set a TTL for an ElasticSearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can set a ttl for a type in the template but can I set a ttl for the entire index? Hmm... I could test this with some guess and check. I'll get around to that and post the answer if I find one.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way internal to ES to automate index deletion.  You'll have to handle that through the API with your client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set TTL for index

**First,** you create a policy to describe when an index will be deleted

PUT http://localhost:9200/_ilm/policy/delete_log_after_2day <- Your policy name

```
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "2d", <-- Set your TTL here
        "actions": {
          "delete": {
            "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Next,** create a template to select which type of index will use this policy.

PUT http://localhost:9200/_index_template/delete_after2day_template

```
{
"index_patterns": [
    "test*" <-- Choose your index here
],
"template": {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "index.lifecycle.name": "delete_log_after_2day"
    }
}
}
```

Now, when you create a new index example: test001 it will be automatically deleted after 2 days.

**Note:**  for the old index, it will not assign to your new policy, so it won't be deleted except you assign it.

You can use this API to assign all old indexes to your policy

PUT http://localhost:9200/test*/_settings <--Your old index here, can use pattern

```
{
  "index": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "name": "delete_log_after_2day" <-- Your policy name
    }
  }
}
```

And then after your expiration date, all old indexes will be deleted completely.